# How to filter combobox values by a field in the source data - Access web app

Tags: ms-access-web-app

I have a combo box in an access web application (list view) that is displaying values from a linked table [Actions].  This table has a Boolean field [Active].

Currently it will show all values from the Actions table in the list, however i would like to filter the list displayed to the user to only include those that are active - i.e [Actions].[Active] = Yes

I am guessing this is possible through an onLoad macro for the view, but cannot work out how to get this working!  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer was to write a query as the source of the combobox...